# Cabal Doesn't Build Executable

Tags: haskell, cabal

For some reason, cabal isn't creating an executable for my program. When I run `cabal build`, I get this output:

```
Building server-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'server' for server-0.1.0.0...
Warning: output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated
because there is no Main module.
```

A subsequent `cabal run` gives me this error:

```
Preprocessing executable 'server' for server-0.1.0.0...
Warning: output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated
because there is no Main module.
cabal: dist/build/server/server: does not exist
```

Sure enough, there is no `server` binary in `dist/build/server/server`. The temp files are, however, in `dist/build/server/server-temp/`.

My `.cabal` file:

```
name:                server
version:             0.1.0.0
synopsis:            An example haskell web service.
license:             Apache-2.0
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Some Body
maintainer:          somebody@gmail.com
category:            Web
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10
executable server
  main-is:             Core/Main.hs
  build-depends:       base,
                       containers,
                       bytestring,
                       bytestring-conversion,
                       aeson,
                       http-types,
                       acid-state,
                       mtl,
                       safecopy,
                       warp,
                       wai,
                       wai-extra,
                       wai-middleware-static
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

My directory structure (including `dist` from `cabal build`):

```
.
├── cabal.sandbox.config
├── dist
│   ├── build
│   │   ├── autogen
│   │   │   ├── cabal_macros.h
│   │   │   └── Paths_server.hs
│   │   └── server
│   │       └── server-tmp
│   │           ├── Core
│   │           │   ├── Main.dyn_hi
│   │           │   ├── Main.dyn_o
│   │           │   ├── Main.hi
│   │           │   └── Main.o
│   │           ├── Model
│   │           │   ├── DB.dyn_hi
│   │           │   ├── DB.dyn_o
│   │           │   ├── DB.hi
│   │           │   └── DB.o
│   │           └── Util
│   │               ├── HTTP.dyn_hi
│   │               ├── HTTP.dyn_o
│   │               ├── HTTP.hi
│   │               └── HTTP.o
│   ├── package.conf.inplace
│   │   └── package.cache
│   └── setup-config
├── LICENSE
├── server.cabal
├── Setup.hs
└── src
    ├── Core
    │   └── Main.hs
    ├── Model
    │   └── DB.hs
    ├── Service
    └── Util
        └── HTTP.hs
```

The `main` definition:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  db <- openLocalStateFrom "~/.acid-state" (UserDatabase Map.empty)
  putStrLn $ "http://localhost:8080/"
  run 8080 $ logStdout $ staticPolicy (noDots >-> addBase "../client/") $ app db
```

Comment: Post your project's `cabal` config file ?

Comment: I've added the config file & dir structure

Comment: Not sure but if you use `Core/Main.hs` is it possible that your module is indeed `Core.Main` if so you still need to make a top-level `Main.hs` with `module Main` without anything else!

Comment: You got it. The issue was that my main module was `Core.Main` and not simply `Main`. I moved `src/Core/Main.hs` to `src/Main.hs` and changed my `main-is:` entry to `Main.hs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's all there in the message:

you need a *source* file defining the *Main* module

```
module Main where ...
```

and exporting a `main`function:

```
main :: IO ()
main = ...
```

and your `main-is` field in your *.cabal* file should point to this.

If you have all this you should be able to compile it into an executable.

Here is a nice intro: [How to write a Haskell programm](https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program)

### update

as it turn out the module was named `Core.Main` - make sure you have one `module Main` too - you can always add a top level `main.hs` and reexport just the `main` from `Core.Main` too

Comment: It does! That's what's weird about it. I'll post my .cabal when I'm back in ~1hr

Comment: Oh - sorry this does not help - I'll let my answer stick for now if you don't mind. Can you post something about your file structure and your the beginning of the file containing your `Main` module too please?

Comment: No worries. I have added my directory structure and my `.cabal` file to the question. I'll also add the `main` definition.

Comment: your main definition only gives the main function, but you don't show the module name. Does your source file start with module Main where as Carsten said?